# How to mock ObjectMapper.readValue() using mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

I'm testing a service layer and not sure how to mock `ObjectMapper().readValue` in that class. I'm fairly new to `mockito` and could figure out how to do it.

The following is my code,

### service.java

```
private configDetail fetchConfigDetail(String configId) throws IOException {
    final String response = restTemplate.getForObject(config.getUrl(), String.class);
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, ConfigDetail.class);
}
```

### ServiceTest.java

```
@Test
public void testgetConfigDetailReturnsNull() throws Exception {

    restTemplate = Mockito.mock(restTemplate.class);
    Service service = new Service();
    Config config = Mockito.mock(Config.class);
    ObjectMapper objMapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
            Mockito.doReturn("").when(restTemplate).getForObject(anyString(), eq(String.class));
    Mockito.doReturn(configDetail).when(objMapper).readValue(anyString(),eq(ConfigDetail.class));
    assertEquals(configDetail, service.getConfigDetail("1234"));
}
```

I get the following results when I run this test,

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
```

Posting ServiceTest.Java here

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConfigServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ConfigPersistenceService persistenceService;

    @InjectMocks
    private ConfigService configService;

    @Mock
    ConfigDetail configDetail;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private ObjectMapper objMapper;

    @Mock
    private Config config;

    @Test
    public void testgetConfigDetailReturnsNull() throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper objMapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(ucpConfig).when(persistenceService).findById("1234");

        Mockito.doReturn("").when(restTemplate).getForObject(anyString(), eq(String.class));

        Mockito.when((objMapper).readValue(“”,ConfigDetail.class)).thenReturn(configDetail);
        assertEquals(ConfigDetail, ConfigService.getConfigDetail("1234"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this question was downvoted I reckon that would help me to understand whats not right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current Service class it would be difficult to mock `ObjectMapper`, `ObjectMapper` is tightly coupled to `fetchConfigDetail` method.

You have to change your service class as follows to mock `ObjectMapper`.

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private configDetail fetchConfigDetail(String configId) throws IOException {
        final String response = restTemplate.getForObject(config.getUrl(), String.class);
        return objectMapper.readValue(response, ConfigDetail.class);
    }
}
```

Here what I did is instead of creating `objectMapper` inside the method I am injecting that from outside (`objectMapper` will be created by Spring in this case)

Once you change your service class, you can mock the `objectMapper` as follows.

```
ObjectMapper mockObjectMapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
Mockito.when(mockObjectMapper.readValue(anyString(), any(ConfigDetail.class)).thenReturn(configDetail);
```

Comment: I did follow the steps as advised here but still running into the same issue. I still see the `objectMapper.readValue(response, ConfigDetail.class)` invoked and please find the call stack as below, `at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4133)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3988)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2992)`

Comment: am I still missing anything here? the expectation here is that the `return objectMapper.readValue(response, ConfigDetail.class);` should not be invoked at all rather simply return the value as mocked in here `Mockito.when(mockObjectMapper.readValue(anyString(), any(ConfigDetail.class)).thenReturn(configDetail);
`. Please advise.

Comment: Post the complete test class

Comment: With that mapper it wouldn't work because the signature of readValue requires a "Class<ConfigDetail>.class" and you are giving a ConfigDetail.class. What would be correct, I know there was a matcher for it but I don't remember where...

Comment: ObjectMapper is not a bean so how do I autowire it?

Answer (score 4):

Problem is with the this line where you are mocking the call to objectmapper.

```
Mockito.when((objMapper).readValue(“”,ConfigDetail.class)).thenReturn(configDetail);
```

**Correct syntax is**

`Mockito.when(objMapper.readValue(“”,ConfigDetail.class)).thenReturn(configDetail);`

Notice the bracket position. When using Spy or Verify, the bracket position is diff. then when using when-then syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Mocking objects created in a SUT is IMO the single biggest limitation of mockito. Use jmockit or powerMock or checkout the offical mockito way of handling this. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation

Answer (score 1):

If you are using junit 5, below line mocks the Objectmapper readvalue(String, Class) method. To avoid ambiguity in the readValue method, we are using typecasting.

```
@Mock
ObjectMapper objMapper;
```

```
Mockito.when(objMapper.readValue((String)Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(configDetail);
```