# How to mock ObjectMapper.readValue() using mockk

Tags: kotlin, mockk, junit-jupiter

There was a similar question asked about Mockito [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575356/how-to-mock-objectmapper-readvalue-using-mockito)

I have a situation where I would like to mock out `readValue` in the following line

```
 val animal: Animal = objectMapper.readValue(String(message.body))
```

I tried

```
@Test
fun `test you filthy animal`() {
    val animal = Animal("bird")

    every {
        objectMapper.readValue(any<String>())
    } returns animal
}
```

...but I keep getting the following error:

`Not enough information to infer type variable T`

I have been scratching my head trying to figure it out in [Mockk](https://mockk.io/).

Answer (score 8):

I ended up figuring it out:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

@Test
fun `test you filthy animal`() {
    val animal = Animal("bird")

    every {
        objectMapper.readValue<Animal>(any<String>())
    } returns animal
}
```

Edit:
Later I ran into more issues that were resolved with the following:

```
every { 
   objectMapper.readValue(any<String>(), any<TypeReference<Animal>>()) 
} returns animal
```

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful for me but it didn't work in all cases. I found kotlin's jacksonObjectMapper() method which gives an object mapper for testing. In that way, doesn't need to handle every case by 'every' but give exact payload for parsing